# Displaying SVG <title> in pop-up box: accessing innerHTML

Tags: jquery, svg

I have taken the unusual step of converting an Adobe Illustrator file into an svg to display as a standalone image. I want to add a layer of interactivity to it -- when the users clicks/mouses over a section of the graphic, I want a pop-up to display the information saved in a  tag in the svg.

Here's a sample of that part of the svg:

```
    <g>
        <path class="st2" d="M128.3,829.3c-33.4-4.2-57-34.6-52.8-67.9c1.8-14,8.4-27,18.7-36.7l26.5,28.2c-8.9,8.4-9.4,22.4-1,31.3
            c3.5,3.8,8.3,6.2,13.4,6.8L128.3,829.3z          ">
<title>White: 36</title>
        </path>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9523 -0.309 0.3094 0.9509 85.6259 788.8041)" class="st3 st11 st13">White</text>
        <text transform="matrix(0.9523 -0.309 0.3094 0.9509 85.6259 788.8041)" class="st4 st11 st13">White</text>
    </g>
```

The class differs between paths, although I could add another class there.

And here's the code I've gotten up to:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Test of interactivity</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .race-number {
    font-size: 59px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='test-box'></div>
<script>
  $.get('Test_int_2-01.svg', function(data) {
    $(document.body).append(data.documentElement);
    init();
  });
  function init() {
    $('path').click(function(){
    console.log($(this)[0].innerHTML);
  });
 }
 </script>
</body>
```

It's already automatically displaying the title when you mouseover the path, but I think that's a default setting, not the result of anything here.

So how do I access that innerHTML and display it? Preferably with some way of styling it with HTML or CSS?

Comment: I should probably add that I originally created this in D3 before moving the project to Illustrator, and D3 was what originally generated the titles. I'm hoping to not have to go back and re-do the D3, since it means completely re-doing the Illustrator part of the graphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Here is the script that automatically does this.

This only works if the svg paths are in this order (path > text > path > text ...)

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("svg")
var count = svg.children.length
var index = []

var reveal = function(a){
 var text = index[a]
 svg.appendChild(text)
}
var hide = function(a){
 var text = index[a]
 text.remove()
}

var n = 0
while(n<count-1){
 svg.children[n].setAttribute("id", n)
 var nn = n+1
 svg.children[nn].setAttribute("id", nn)
 index.push(svg.children[nn])
 n+=2
}
var q = 1
 while(q<=count){
 document.getElementById(q).remove()
 q+=2
 }
var nnn = 0
 while(nnn<index.length){
 svg.children[nnn].setAttribute("onmouseover", "reveal("+nnn+")")
 svg.children[nnn].setAttribute("onmouseout", "hide("+nnn+")")
 nnn++
}
```

```html
<svg height="1000" width="1000" id="svg">

        <path 
  d="M 50,50, 75,50 75,75 50,75 z"
  fill="yellow">
        </path>
        <text x="50" y="50" style="fill:gold;">gold</text>
  
  <path 
  d="M 500,200, 700,200 700,400 500,400 z"
  fill="blue">
        </path>
        <text x="600" y="300" style="fill:black;">Black</text>
  
  <path 
  d="M 200,200, 400,200 400,400 200,400 z"
  fill="red">
        </path>
        <text x="300" y="300" style="fill:white;">White</text>
  
  
  <path 
  d="M 500,200, 700,200 700,400 500,400 z"
  fill="blue">
        </path>
        <text x="600" y="300" style="fill:black;">Black</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: There are hundreds of paths. Is there a way to create an id automatically for each of them?

Comment: Probably not the best practice but updated code for what you need. You just have to put the Paths and Texts in the right order like noted.